# Dynamic combo box names

Tags: c#

I'm working with C#. I want to use string variables as combo box names.
Suppose, I have 3 combo box named `box1`, `box2` and `box3`. Now I want to change some properties of these combo boxes.
I can write:

```
box1.SomeProperty = SomeValue1;
box2.SomeProperty = SomeValue2;
box3.SomeProperty = SomeValue3;
```

But I want to do it within a `for` or `while` loop. Like:

```
string[] names = new string[3] {"box1","box2","box3"};
int[] values= new int[3] {4,5,6};
for (int i = 0; i <= names.Length; i++)
{
    ?names[i]?.SomeProperty = values[i];
}
```

`?name[i]?` is replaced by strings from the `names` variable.
This is my first post. Please forgive the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a set of controls you know you'll want to update, just create a collection:

```
var comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox> { box1, box2, box3 };

foreach (var cb in comboBoxes)
{
    cb.SomeProperty = SomeValue1;
}
```

If you really wanted to use names, you could search for them in the current Form's Controls collection (assuming this is WinForms... you didn't specify):

```
var comboBoxes = new List<string> { "box1", "box2", "box3" };

foreach (var cb in comboBoxes)
{
    var box = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find(cb, true).FirstOrDefault();

    if (box != null)
        box.SomeProperty = SomeValue1;
}
```

If you want to modify *all* ComboBox controls on the current Form (again, assuming WinForms), you could use LINQ's [`OfType<>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) method in conjunction with the Controls collection:

```
foreach (var cb in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
    cb.SomeProperty = SomeValue1;
}
```

Comment: Thought the second solution didn't work, the first one worked. And it fulfilled my requirements. I actually wanted to use a loop to change the values so that when there are many of them I can handle those easily. So it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work quite as you're expecting..

I would instead build a list of ComboBox controls, and then iterate through this list of objects to apply the property changes.

If you have three ComboBoxes on your form named box1, box2, box3... then you should be able to do the following:

```
List<ComboBox> boxes = new List<ComboBox>();
boxes = {box1, box2, box3}.ToList;

int[] values = {4, 5, 6};

for (i = 0; i <= boxes.Count - 1; i++) {
    boxes(i).SomeProperty = values(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your controls are on a form, and your code is also running on the same form access the controls through the forms Controls collection using the key. The key is the control name.

```
this.Controls[names[i]].SomeProperty = values[i];
```